# Mounted HDD formatted NTFS to Pi 3b, having some quirks

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I am running a RetroPie image that downloads ROM sets directly to my Pi. As you can guess I ran out of space on my SD card.

I decided to purchase a desktop hdd, seagate 3 TB with external power supply. I was trying to get the image to download directly to the HDD, found some tutorials online that had me unmounting `sda1` and `sda2` and remounting.

I am brand new to all this using SSH, Linux, command prompts etc. Ended up not being able to do anything on my Pi, it would load into shh and would not accept any commands.

Finally got a fix an emulation station would not read HDD or SD card. Ended up reflashing my image as I was told that was 'factory reset'. Now when emulation station loads I have the retropie menu and one emulator.

If I restart emulation station I have all my roms, except the one on the SD card and the RetroPie menu.

Rom service has been turned on and off several times as part of troubleshooting with no luck.

The HDD is formated in NTFS, I also have a 128 gb usb stick formated in FAT32 that behaves the same way.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem that the Emulation Station needs to be reloaded to list all the ROMs?

Comment: Thats part of my issue, the other is that what is on the sd card to not being copied to the hdd.

Comment: What command did you use to copy data from sd to the hard disk. ?

Comment: just enabled the usb rom service, formatted the hdd in ntfs, and created a folder called retropie-mount. That was all before i messed around in ssh. I will have to try and find the commands

Comment: Format your usb device in nfts using RetroPie as labelsudo umount /dev/sda1

sudo mkdir /mnt/usb

sudo touch /home/pi/RetroPie/retropiemenu/ThisIsSD.sh

sudo cp -r /home/pi/RetroPie/* /mnt/usb

sudo touch /mnt/usb/retropiemenu/ThisIsUSB.sh

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

The tricky part is that you must add right ABOVE exit0 those 2 lines
umount /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /home/pi/RetroPie

(Now save and close nano editor with ctrl+o then enter then ctrl+x)

sudo reboot now

Comment: These are the list of commands that I was told to run to get information to download directly to the pi. After doing this my pi stopped reading both the hdd and the usb stick. When it rebooted it would take me the the shh script. Could not input any commands through the pi it's self or using putty.  I was getting help through a fb group, and there next suggestion was to re flash the sd card. Sorry for the long stories just wanting to give as much info as possible. Hopefully someone can see where I have gone astray. Thanks again.